# Functions such that $f''(x_0) = 0$ where $x=x_0$ is not a point of inflection

Tags: calculus

I recently learned that if $ f''(x) = 0 $ this is a possible inflection point. I've been told that it's a **possible** inflection point, since the curvature of the graph needs to change. I'm trying to visualise/come up with a function where $f''(x)=0$ but the point for which this happens is not a inflection point. Could someone give me a function or two subject to these conditions please?

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081212/sketching-a-graph/2081274

Answer (score 5):

If $f(x)=x^4$ and $x_0=0$ then $f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)=0$ but $x_0$ is not an inflection point because the concavity of $f(x)$ doesn't change at $x_0$. The same is true for $x^6,x^8$, and so on at zero.

Comment: It will also be true for $f(x)=e^{−x^4}$ and for any function of the form $f(x)=e^{−x^{2n}}$ where n is a positive integer.

Comment: @BernardMassé You mean when $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @J.G. Of course...